# How to connect Adminer when running in Docker container and DB is Postgres AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, docker-compose, amazon-rds, adminer

I'm trying to connect to adminer on port 8080 that is running in a docker container which is running in an EC2 instance. The database is running in an AWS RDS instance. Both are running in the same VPC. I can connect via the cli to the RDS instance but I can't use my browser to connect to RDS through adminer running domain.com:8080.
I don't know if the security groups are setup correctly and I don't really know what needs to be added to the security groups. Any advice? Thanks in advance.

```
adminer:
  build:
    context: ../ 
    dockerfile: ./path/to/adminer/Dockerfile
  ports:
    - "8080:8080"
  environment:
    - POSTGRES_CONNECTION=psql
    - POSTGRES_HOST=**********
    - POSTGRES_DB=**********
    - POSTGRES_USER=**********
    - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=**********
    - POSTGRES_PORT=5432
 networks:
    - backend
```

Comment: Ok I had everything setup correctly but I was trying to access adminer from `https://example.com:8080`. I had to access it without the ssl via `http://example.com:8080`. Does anyone know how to access adminer via a secure connection?

Comment: Hello Chris, did you have any info about accessing adminer ssl?

Comment: No. I forgot about this and haven't tried to figure it out.